# Connected and Unconnected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph, G = (V,E), and conditions on members of V (that they must be connected to some m vertices, and disconnected to some n vertices), how can I efficiently find candidates for removal, based on m and n?
I keep coming up with the fact that once I've removed some v in V, I must then start again and search through the set V again to find objects that meet this criteria (as removing some v from V is going to have an affect on other members of V). 
Am I missing something obvious - or should I be looking into achieving what I'm trying in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

One way in which you can do this is to apply the [max-flow min-cut theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem).

Specifically, mark a random node as your source $s$, another node as your sink $t$, and then identify the arcs involved in the maximum flow carried from $s$ to $t$. By the above theorem, removal of these arcs leads to a separation in your graph such that $s$ is in one disconnected component, and $t$ is in another one.

You can do this more efficiently by labeling lexicographically your nodes, e.g., node $1$, node $2$, ..., node $n$, and then run $n-1$ max-flows from node $1$ to all the other $n-1$ nodes and identify such components. Combine this with your prior constraints to further reduce your computational burden.